# Best Way to Approach Android XML Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Everything will be coming from JSON objects. I'm fairly new to android layouts, what android elements should I use to achieve this goal? I've been reading about listviews, however I'm not sure that would be the best approach. Currently they are textviews and images that change to the JSON data.

I will also be changing the "Switch button" from the bottom to a tab based layout.

[image: screen mock-up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall layout can be achieved using a couple of linear layout containers.

Coming to each list view, this can be achieved using Listview. Here is an example of what you can do in a list view. This is a screen from one of my android applications:
http://lh5.ggpht.com/_HV69Hrxy0Wk/Tb1xyr0NQdI/AAAAAAAADEA/7zrweuhgNTA/s1600-h/NA_Shard_Status%5B2%5D.png

Here is a link to a tutorial:
http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/multicolumn-listview-with-image-icon/

Comment: Great, From the tutorial I should make the layout in a separate XML file, and then have the listview adopt that for each element? Definitely starts to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the data you've shown there is clearly some sort of list, so your best bet would be a ListView. Or, if you wanted your list items to expand when you click on them you could use an ExpandableListView.

If the data is dynamic and loaded from JSON then a ListView with an Adapter is certainly your best bet, that way you don't have to change any xml/java code if you add or remove items in your underlying data set (the json file).

As for the tabs, the best way of implementing those is with Fragments. I posted quite recently on my blog about implementing swipe-able tab views in Android that you [might find useful.](http://storkme.org/2011/12/tabs-done-right-viewpager-and-fragments/) (the end result looks similar to the android marketplace app, where you tabs that you can also scroll horizontally between).